# When I try to play a 3D game, I cannot hold down a key and move my trackpad simultaneously. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, laptop, touchpad

I am trying to play a 3D game (minecraft). This requires me to be able to hold W and move my trackpad at all times. Whenever I try to move my mouse while holding the W key, it locks up and doesn't let me move it. This happens outside of the game application as well. I have seen that others have the same issue, but none of those solutions work for my specific computer model. I am on an HP Pavillion and I have an ELAN touchpad. Someone please help. ps. I have also just updated Windows, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the ELAN driver and software?  You probably don't need it and it is probably what is causing this to happen.  If it turns out that you want it back.. reinstall it.  Also, probably won't need it but keep a USB mouse handy in case you lose mouse functionality

Comment: I don't really have a USB mouse available. I haven't messed with anything and am not the most educated in this kind of thing. Thank you for responding, I will see if anyone else has a solution for me.

Comment: I hope someone does Jadon.  You can get a usb mouse for as little as a couple of dollars.. or MOST PEOPLE have at least one laying around.. borrow one before removing the driver/software.  You problem is very likely tied to the ELAN drivers.  If you need help uninstalling them, ask a new question ;) .. MANY MANY techs here are more than happy to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour for some touchpad drivers to stop you from accidentally moving the mouse while you are typing.

There is usually a setting in your mouse application which will allow you to disable anything called "palm sense" or "smart sense".
As someone has mentioned, you should be able to remove the touchpad drivers, and then Windows will revert back to the default driver, which will not have this functionality enabled.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `Driver manager`
- Right click on `Mice and other pointing devices`. Select `Update driver`.
- `Search automatically` and `Search on Windows Update`
- On Windows Update, select `View additional updates`.
- One of the updates must be for your touchpad, find the one and install.
- After installing update (which usually requires restart), you must see `Synaptics touchpad` on Start menu (Type `touchpad` to see it)

After that the solution varies but in my case, I opened SmartSense setting, I made every setting off(slided to the most left). It still does not work perfectly but at least gives a few seconds before disabling again.